# Generalized taxicab numbers: pairs of squares

Tags: elementary-number-theory

While doodling with stuff on Mathematica, I noticed that, empirically, every generalized taxicab number to be representable as multiple sums of two (non-zero) squares is divisible by five:

$\forall n > 1 : 5 \mid \mathrm{Taxicab}(2, 2, n)$

($Taxicab$ defined in [Generalized taxicab number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_taxicab_number).)

This observation is purely empirical, but seems to hold at least to taxicab numbers of value 10<sup>10</sup>. Some of the smallest sums of two squares that can be represented in $n$ distinct ways are:

$5^2 + 5^2 = 7^2 + 1^2 = 50$

$15^2 + 10^2 = 17^2 + 6^2 = 18^2 + 1^2 = 325$

$24^2 + 23^2 = 31^2 + 12^2 = 32^2 + 9^2 = 33^2 + 4^2 = 1105$

... and this goes on. For instance, $8800358125$ is the smallest such an integer that can be expressed $50$ different ways, and $6076533125$ can be expressed in $80$ ways.

I can't help thinking that this is a well known result. Is there a proof for this conjecture?

**EDIT**: I note that known $\mathrm{Taxicab}(3, 2, n)$ numbers (except the trivial case of $n = 1$) are divisible by $7$.

Comment: You could look at http://oeis.org/A016032 and http://oeis.org/A048610 and the references

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Thanks to A016032 and Ross Millikan's comment, the reason why appears to have been solved [here](http://www.primepuzzles.net/puzzles/puzz_062.htm) by Joseph Culbertson. It follows Nate's answer and has to do with primes in the form $4k + 1$.

[Another link](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~mackay/sumsquares.pdf)

Comment: I choose this answer, not because Nate's answer would be wrong, but because the referred page is really a bit more approachable for an armchair mathematician like me. Also, the page shows people have certainly thought of this before.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose a number can be written $N = 2^tp_1^{a_1}...p_k^{a_k}q_1^{b_1}...q_l^{b_l}$ where the $p_i$ are primes congruent to 1 mod 4, and the $q_i$ are primes congruent to 3 mod 4. Then:

A) $N$ can be written as a sum of two squares iff each b_i is even.

B) In this case N can be written as an $ordered$ sum of two squares of $integers$ in $4(a_1+1)(a_2+1)...(a_k+1)$.

Note that part B counts squares of negatives and 0 as well, so for example $5=1^2+2^2=2^2+1^2=(-1)^2+2^2=2^2+(-1)^2=...$ eight ways total.

This theorem follows from unique factorization in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, I suggest looking up Fermat's two squares theorem. From here, showing this multiple of 5 property is pretty easy.

Comment: I believe OP is asking for the smallest number expressed as $n$ squares summed.

Comment: @qwr Actually, smallest number expressed as two squares summed, representable in $n$ distinct ways... Think of taxicab numbers ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_number ), but with squares instead of cubes.